# Finding relationship between variables

Tags: data-science, correlation, supervised-learning, unsupervised-learning

There are two sets: 
 
A: 1 2 3 
 
B : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
 
Points in A serve to multiple points in B. for example: 
 
A 1: B 1 2 4 
 
A 2: B 3 5 6 
 
A 3: B 7 8 9 10

Given historical data of points in both A and B set, how to determine the which point in A is serving to points in set B?

Answer (score 0):

Encode A and B columns as vectors and fit classification model. Then, after fitting, you can make predictions for various inputs of A ((1, 0, 0) as an example) and get probabilities in vector B ((0.25, 0.5, 0.1, ..., 0.15) as an example). So, in this case, value 1 for A serves values (1, 2, 3, 10) with probabilities above.  Depending on the task, you can select some threshold.

Depending on the data you need to select an encoding method (dummy vs one-hot), model, think about sampling, metric and so on.